# How to debug nativescript in local chrome & local emulator

Tags: nativescript

Not able to run nativescript in local chrome/emulator

installed Android studo, added emulators in avd manager, but on clicking launch avd in emulator nothing happened.

tried from terminal, tns device

Connected devices & emulators
Searching for devices...
iTunes is not installed. Install it on your system and run this command again.
Cannot find connected devices. Reconnect any connected devices, verify that your system recognizes them, and run this command again.

and

tns run android
Skipping node_modules folder! Use the syncAllFiles option to sync files from this folder.
Searching for devices...
Starting Android emulator with image Nexus_5X_API_28
Cannot find connected devices.
Emulator start failed with: Cannot run the app in the selected native emulator. Try to restart the adb server by running the `adb kill-server` command in the Command Prompt, or increase the allocated RAM of the virtual device through the Android Virtual Device manager. NativeScript CLI users can try to increase the timeout of the operation by adding the `--timeout` flag.
To list currently connected devices and verify that the specified identifier exists, run 'tns device'.
To list available emulator images, run 'tns device  --available-devices'.

some explain what is missing here

Comment: which are the command you tried and be detailed so one can help you.

Comment: Are you on Windows? Try running `tns devices android` after starting your emulator / connecting your device to machine, and see whether it lists the emulator / device.